# When asking facebook access token in exchange for authorization code,facebook is not responding in spring social?

Tags: spring-social-facebook

After the user's authorization, i'm redirected back to my application with authorization code, but when i asked for access grant in exchange of authorization code i'm getting connection timeout error. Facebook is not responding

```
AccessGrant accessGrant =auth2Operations.exchangeForAccess(code, "my redirect url", null);
```

please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the same redirect URL as in the first step of the authentication, i.e., in user's authorization?

Comment: No, i didn't at first but now i corrected it by having same url, and also i have added the proxy url and port, Now its working...

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","192.168.2.41");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same `URLCallback` in all the steps of oAuth authentication process. If not, you will receive an error from Facebook

Comment: Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817775/error-when-creating-bean-for-connection-repository-in-spring-social-facebook-con